# Create new form with Sharepoint 365 Small Business Edition

Tags: sharepoint-online

I lost my Newform.aspx for one of my lists.  I can't use SharePoint Designer because it won't let me upload a form. How do I recreate a new form? Or, can I copy, e.g., the EditForm and make it into a newform?

Comment: What exactly do you mean, you "lost it"? How did that happen? Did you lose the "Add new Item" link? When you try to access the new form, what do you see? What permissions do you have on the list?